# JTextArea that needs to grow with parent panel

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, layout-manager

I want to make my JTextArea field as big as it can be in current JPanel. How to do that?

Now it is like this:

```
    JPanel statusBar = new StatusBar(project);
    JTextArea outputBox = new JTextArea(1, 50); 
    outputBox.setEditable(true);
    statusBar.add(outputBox);
```

Comment: Use the appropriate Layout Manager that will allow it to grow. See the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. Also, you would generally add the text area to a scroll pane.

Answer (score 5):

The default layout manager of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, which wouldn't let the text area fill the entire available space in the panel.

Using `BorderLayout` should work well:

```
statusBar.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
JTextArea outputBox = new JTextArea(1, 50); 
outputBox.setEditable(true);
statusBar.add(outputBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a layout manager on the JPanel.  If its just the JTextArea contained within it and you need to maximise it you can use a simple GridLayout:

```
   statusBar.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
```